# How to point out unclear things in an answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-answer

I have never edited someone else's answer before and I am not sure what's best way to point out unclear parts.

Would Wikipedia style be a good approach - to leave short remarks like *"confusing part"* or *"what does this mean?"*

The answer is the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861184/what-is-the-difference-between-git-init-and-git-init-bare).

For example:

> You still can push to a repository that's not bare, but you will get rejected as you can potentially move a branch that someone is working on in that working directory.

Should I edit it like this?

> How can I push if I will get rejected?
>   What does it mean to "potentially move a branch"?
>   You move it or you don't.

Should I just comment here with *"unclear, example needed"* (wikipedia style).

Or should I I put these concerns in comments which is very illegible and I'll probably need like 3-5 comments to clear stuff out?

Because take a look at very next sentence:

> **So in a project with no working folder, you can only see the objects as git stores them.** They are compressed and serialized and stored under the SHA1 (a hash) of their contents. In order to g**et an object in a bare repository**, you need to git show and then specify the sha1 of the object you want to see. You won't see a structure like what your project looks like.

What does the first sentence this mean? How do I otherwise not see objects as git stores them? How is this different?

Then what does it mean to *"get an object in a bare repository"*?

Comment: You should **never** edit a question to ask for clarification. That IS what comments are for.

Comment: Note that even in Wikipedia one is not supposed to directly add questions and remarks about an article to the article itself. That is done either through special-purpose templates, which clearly set such meta-content apart from the main body of the text, or in the talk pages. We don't have an analogue of the meta-content templates here; as for the talk pages, comments play a similar role.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Don't edit comments into an answer like that.

If you feel a answer is unclear, comment on the answer, and ask for clarification.

Comment: While this perfectly answers the question I think there is a difference between "answer is unclear" and "I don't get the answer" (I've added post that may clarify that).

Answer (score 3):

- Don't ever add questions into an answer.
- If you feel answer is *generally* unclear - add comments asking for clarifications about particular statements. Consider if downvote is appropriate.
- If you *personally* don't understand the answer - asking new question linking to existing one is likely better option. After your new question gets answered - consider if commenting on original post would be appropriate.

There is huge difference between not understanding an answer (article, book,...) and that answer being unclear. There is a very good chance you are missing a lot of context implied by the answer. If you can't understand post - make sure to read documentation on the subject first.

I.e. it would be inappropriate to ask for clarifications "what is derivative" for question like [What's the accuracy difference between the two versions derivative calculation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945026/whats-the-accuracy-difference-between-the-two-versions-derivative-calculation) even if you don't know what derivative is. Context of the question implies that one already understands at least basics of calculus and does not need a book to clarify every statement. If that would not be the case most of the questions have to be closed as "too broad" as every detail need to be explained.